# Highlight the rows that have attribute with empty string

Tags: c#, xml

assume i have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Logging S="T006" version="2" >
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="22" ID="Opened" Msg="some text"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="76" ID="Auth"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="60" ID="Up"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Warning" id="22" ID="Opened" Msg="some text"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="96" ID="Locked"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="84" ID="Done"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="16" ID="Inspected" Pos=""/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="10" ID="Inspected" Pos="12"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="57" ID="Idle"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="17" ID="Inspected" Pos=""/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="148" ID="Started"/>
</Logging>
```

I want to filter the attributes where the "Pos" has no value, so it's empty string like this: Pos=""
first I use StreamReader to parse the xml file like this:

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = @"All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            m_Logfile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            var dataset = new DataSet();
            dataset.ReadXml(sr);

            var bindingSource = new BindingSource
            {
                DataSource = dataset,
                DataMember = "Log"
            };
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;

        }
```

I use color to higlight the rows with empty Pos like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string pos = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Pos"].Value.ToString();

            if(pos == "")
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
         }
```

but in result I get the whole table highlighted ! not only the rows with Pos empty. So I have two questions for this code :

1. How can I highlight only those rows that have attribute Pos=""  ?
2. How can I add more conditions to filter more Pos , for example something like this :
   `if(pos == "12" && pos == "" && ID == "Opened") { dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow; }` I know this doesn't work, but how can I add more AND or && in one "if statement" instead of keep adding "else if" for this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no null values in the dataset after ReadXml method call. All missing Pos attributes are replaced with empty strings. So don't use dataset to work with xml if you want keep nulls.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So what apporach do you recommend?